# Cloning a Drupal site

Tags: php, drupal

I need to build a testing site (as a copy of the "real site").
I did the following:

- copy the whole "real site" to `/var/www/html/drupal-test`
- clone de database as a new database called `drupal-db-test`
- made changes on `/var/ww/html/drupal/sites/default/settings.php` to specify the location of the testing db

Then I open a browser and when I ask for `localhost/drupal-test` i get the following error message back:

```
The requested URL `/drupal-test/ca/user/password` was not found on this server
```

What I've tried is to ask for `localhost/drupal-test/?q=user/login`. I found this solution in the Internet, and it works, I can now see the login page. However, the problem is still there because when I enter user and password, I get another error:

```
The requested URL `/drupal-test/ca/whatever` was not found on this server
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So basically “pretty URLs” don’t seem to be working. Check if you are allowed to use the necessary modules (mod_rewrite?) on your test server. Also, try and disable them on the site your are copying _from_ first, and then clone the database.

Comment: "Check if you are allowed to use the necessary modules (mod_rewrite?) on your test server" ........ How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Also try to clear the cache in the db with these request sql : TRUNCATE cache; TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

If you don't want to modify apache config file (as in my case, so I have more than a single webpage in my server), you can do the following:

Login as an administrator in your Drupal interface, and click "configuration" -> (Search and metadata) Clean Urls -> Disable clean URL's

Thanks anyway :D